# Hide a table row depending on value

Tags: javascript, php

I am using PHP to pull info from a database. The code pulls a time and date from the data base then checks to see if that date has passed or not.

The table is populated with the time from the database and "Yes" or "No" depending if the date has passed.

I would like to be able to hide all the rows that return "No".

I have tried the following but cannot seem to get it to work.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">$("#results table tbody tr td").filter(function() {
return $(this).text() === "No";
}).parent().hide();</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
$("#results table tbody tr td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "No";
}).parent().hide();
</script>
```

you should have two script tags:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#results table tbody tr td").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() === "No";
    }).parent().hide();
});
</script>
```

If `script` has `src` property its content is not executed. Also you may need to wrap your code into DOMContentLoaded block `$(function() { ... })` if your scripts are in `<head>`.

Comment: Check one more time, there should be something. Code is ok http://jsfiddle.net/P8evf/

Comment: My bad, I was trying to associate it with "table id = 'results'" instead of warping it in a div. Cheers for that JSfiddle, other wise I would of missed that. Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

You added the javascript code in the `jquery script`,for that you need another `script`

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#results table tbody tr td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "No";
    }).parent().hide();
  });
    </script>
```